# JPA - Getting "Transaction Required" Exception on persisting an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, wildfly

I have my maven application set up and wildfly server running. I have a mySql datasource that I can read from using my EntityManager but in every attempt to persist my entity I get the error saying "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress"

Bellow is my BaseDao class

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class BaseDao {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "MySqlDS";
    private EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

And my persistemce.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MySqlDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>main.java.yas.entity.User</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my service class that calls the manager is as follows:

```
public class UserService {

    @EJB
    private UserManager manager;

    public String createNewUser_test(String name) {
        return manager.createNewUser_test(name);
    }
}
```

And my manager class is like this:

```
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Stateless
public class UserManager {

    public String createNewUser_test(String name) {

        BaseDao dao = new BaseDao();
        EntityManager em = dao.getEntityManager();
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName(name);
            user.setLastName(name);
            user.setRole(UserRole.RegistredUser);
            user.setEmail("email@email.com");

            em.persist(user);

        }
        finally {
            em.flush();
            em.close();
        }

    }
}
```

I have checked and I am stating the "jta = true" in the wildfly standalone.xml file.

can you please tell me what is wrong in my application?

Updates:
 I applied some changes that some of the reviewers suggested. Now I'm getting the NPE in the service class where I'm calling the manager to create the new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're manually instantiating your DAO, and manually building your persistence unit.  When you do this, JTA is not enabled even if you've configured it in your `persistence.xml`.  Is there a reason why you can't use injection in this case?

If you wanted to switch to injection, a very simple approach based on what you're doing right now would look like this.

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class BaseDao {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MySqlDS")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void save(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }
}

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class UserManager {
    @EJB
    private BaseDao baseDao;
    public String createNewUser_test(String name) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(name);
        user.setLastName(name);
        user.setRole(UserRole.RegistredUser);
        user.setEmail("email@email.com");

        baseDao.save(user);
        return "";
    }
}
```

In this example, the container instantiates your classes for you and can provide resources as needed, such as the `EntityManager` provided here.

Comment: No, there is not any particular reason. It's just that I'm not very familiar with different methods. Could you tell me how can I instantiate the DAO with injection?

Comment: When I use @EJB annotation to inject my beans, first call to any method of the bean causes NPE, as if the instance of the bean is not initialized. I tried your method but at baseDao.save(user); I get a NPE.

Comment: How are you getting a reference to `UserService`?  To clarify, you shouldn't be instantiating it.  Use the pattern in my post to convert UserService into an EJB and inject it into whatever you're calling it from.

Comment: Actually, in this case, JTA is enabled even if you are manually creating your persistence unit. BaseDao is instantiated manually, but it doesn't have to be injected, it is enough that UserManager is injected as this is the bean which has the business method.

Comment: @Szarpul you may want to review this https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions

Comment: @JohnAment I did read it, and it says: "JTA transactions can be used in two modes in Java EE. .... The second mode allows the EntityManager to be application managed, (normally obtained from an injected EntityManagerFactory, or directly from JPA Persistence).". So you can have JTA enabled when you create your EntityManagerFactory with Persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@TransactionAttribute` attribute, it is by default set to `REQUIRED`, which is enough for you.

How do you obtain your UserManager object?

If you want the container to start the transaction automatically with the method, it has to be container-managed, which means your bean has to be injected like:

```
@EJB
UserManager userManager;
```

Comment: Do you mean @EJB UserManager userManager? or UserTransaction must be injected in my manager class? sorry I got a bit confused.

Comment: I meant @EJB UserManager userManager- your bean has to be injected

Comment: I tried that now the way I instantiate my Manager class is as follows:
@EJB
    private UserManager manager;
and then I call the createNewUser_test() method, but it gives me a NPE

Comment: You can inject your bean only in other container managed beans, like servlet, managed bean, CDI bean or other EJB bean. You can not inject it in simple POJO object.